# Best practice for storing monthly payment data for members

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Say i'm an organisation with a bunch of members, who are all expected to pay monthly. Some pay each for the entire year the first month, and the price to pay differs per person. Some of these payments are made via another organisation, that will send a csv file to us with the amount paid as well as userid which we can use to import into our database to register the payment. the others are entered via our site manually. where you can enter the amount paid for each month in the current year. previous years are stored in an archive database. What would be the most efficient way to design the database keeping in mind it is automated for the most part?

My website is entirely coded on PHP and im using a MySQL database with it. While i could create a cronjob to generate me a new table for each year, i prefer to make something that would require the least amount of effort possible. No manual creation of new columns or tables would be nice. so if im on a 10 year holiday, the site could continue on its own each year

My own guess would be to create a new column for each month in the table i keep all my users data.  but this means that every year i have to manually update the code and the database for the new year. surely there's a more effiecient way but honestly i have no idea what is considered the most efficient method for this. i could create what i have in mind now but i'm not sure if that could guarantee decent performance if, lets say, the userbase expands drastically

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You should store one table of invoices, with an invoice id.

Another table of payments.  If you can guarantee that each payment exactly matches an invoice, then that table should have an `invoice_id` on it.

In the real world, things are not so simple.  So, you can have a junction table that matches each payment to the invoice it belongs to.  This is a separate table, to handle the situations:

- Multiple payments are made for a single invoice.
- One payment applies to multiple invoices.
- Payments may partially pay for one or more invoices.

Comment: In particular, do _not_ have a column for every month and do _not_ have a table for each year.  You _will_ need application code (PHP) to reconcile whether everyone is paid up; SQL can help, but have PHP do the messier cases.